# The King and the Oracle

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, story, history

There was a king that wanted to go to war. But before that, he decided to go see the Oracle of the nearest temple, in order to estimate his chances and to have a clearer vision of his destiny.
However, oracles always seem to speak nonsense (and with poor grammar), and this one was no exception.

> *The King* - Greetings, wise Oracle. Tell me, if the Gods approve, where should I go to war?
>
> ***The Oracle* - Gamble strike a feline throw just away the useless french wine.**
>
> *The King* - That... is not very helpful... And what is "french" anyway? Nevermind, my next question is: will I win this war?
>
> ***The Oracle* - Evil persons speech, planet on dessert stack. Inspiring rodent sense fish on upper leg. Float above the wicked person of sorcerer era.**
>
> *The King* - It doesn't seem so good... But still, how will I be remembered after all of this?
>
> ***The Oracle* - Family ruler, of parasite ruse. Mark negation, proud dragon on marathon track.**
>
> *The King* - Somewhat better, I guess. Lastly, how will I die?
>
> ***The Oracle* - Hide demand and dry clear of dodging small bird. Automatic ship with swimming pilot, a furious pace on scepter path.**
>
> *The King* - I'll look out for birds then? Thank you, wise Oracle, even if I'm not sure what to think of all this.

---

**Who was this king, and what were the Oracle's predictions?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suspect the king may have been

> Alexander the Great.

The oracle speaks

> pairs of words whose synonyms differ with one letter. The differing letters form the answer.

The King - Greetings, wise Oracle. Tell me, if the Gods approve, where should I go to war?

The Oracle - Gamble strike a feline throw just away the useless french wine.

> be(A)t, ca(S)t, fa(I)r, v(A)in → **ASIA**. Alexander definitely campaigned there extensively.

The King - That... is not very helpful... And what is "french" anyway? Nevermind, my next question is: will I win this war?

The Oracle - Evil persons speech, planet on dessert stack. Inspiring rodent sense fish on upper leg. Float above the wicked person of sorcerer era.

> me(A)n, wor(L)d<sup>1</sup>, pi(L)e, m(O)use, (F)eel, (T)high, (H)over, m(E)an, (M)age → **ALL OF THEM**. Alexander did conquer a vast area during his reign.

The King - It doesn't seem so good... But still, how will I be remembered after all of this?

The Oracle - Family ruler, of parasite ruse. Mark negation, proud dragon on marathon track.

> kin(G), t(R)ick, not(E), sm(A)ug<sup>1</sup>, (T)race → **GREAT**, which is indeed the byname we now use for him.

The King - Somewhat better, I guess. Lastly, how will I die?

The Oracle - Hide demand and dry clear of dodging small bird. Automatic ship with swimming pilot, a furious pace on scepter path.

> (M)ask, (A)rid, duck(L)ing, bo(A)t, d(R)iver<sup>1</sup>, (I)rate, ro(A)d → **MALARIA**. There are differing theories about Alexander's cause of death including typhoid fever and assassination, but malaria is one of the plausible ones.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Solved by Stiv in the comments</sub>

Comment: Definitly quicker than I expected, well done! Let's see if people can find the speech planet, dodging small bird & swimming pilot. Also, I had something else in mind for proud dragon, but yours fit in quite nicely ;)

Comment: Great work jafe :) I think rot13(fcrrpu cynarg = jbe(Y)q)

Comment: @Stiv Added, thanks!

Comment: Wrong section there though! The best I have for the other two are rot13(gv(Y)g naq q(E)vire) - least sure of the bird one.

Comment: @Stiv As for the proud dragon, I had something else in mind for the bird one, but yours could work too :)

Comment: @Keelhaul Ah, in that case I reckon you were probably thinking of rot13(s(Y)vapu naq Fz(n)ht)!

Comment: @Stiv Yes for the dragon, but there's *yet another* possibility for the bird :p

Comment: I think the rot13(qbqtvat fznyy oveq) is a rot13(sYvapu).

Comment: @Keelhaul Pretty sure I have the right bird now!

Comment: The intended one, yes, since the other could be right too :)